# Explanation of class loading in an EAR for non-requested but dependent class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classloader, apache-commons-logging

I'm trying to track down a problem I'm having in WAS 6.1 with AXIS 1 and Commons Logging. My EAR is set to parent last. In the ear is commons-logging, Axis and a client jar that uses Axis. The classes in the client jar are called from a WAR.

The WAR calls the client, which calls the axis jar, which needs commons-logging. But it does not appear as if the EAR is loading commons-logging from itself. It looks like commons-logging is coming from WebSphere.

Then another class in the WAR directly asks for commons-logging and the EAR appears to be loading it. As a result I'm getting this error: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl incompatible with org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

Is there anything I can do to prevent this? Am I reading the situation wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since both commons-logging and Axis 1 are built into WAS 6.1, I'd try to remove them from the EAR and WARs entirely; you could then set your classloader policy to the default "PARENT_FIRST", which is certainly more robust.

You'll still need Axis and jcl to compile your code, so only eliminate them from the EAR. If you use Maven, that would mean changing their scope to "provided", with Ant that would be constructing the jar list separately for the ear task, with Eclipse EAR project — removing appropriate jars from the Deployment Assembly.

I'd be grateful for a short info how you did.

Comment: While I do appreciate your insight, I'm not going to count this as answered. Specifically I'm trying to figure out how the system is seemingly double loading commons logging. I might try removing Axis on Monday, but that is merely to assuage the configuration. But again, thanks for the insight about what WAS provides.

Comment: @Virmundi Now I don't know what your goal is - to fix the problem, or to ponder on why, oh, why it's not working. You probably have different versions of jcl library, so some classes get loaded from the EAR and some from WAS.

Comment: And that is my question, in this way I'm a bit existential. I pulled jcl before posting the question. It worked fine. But I want to know what part of my class loading knowledge is either wrong or incomplete. Since the ear is parent last, only the ears version of the jcl library should have loaded. Apparently this isn't the case.

Comment: Axis 1 does not appear to be part of the base install for WAS 6.1. It might be part of the install for WAS 6.1 Web Service Extention.

Comment: @Virmundi That's really strange - IBM's redbook (http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247257.pdf, page 173) claims that Axis has been the part of WAS since version 5.0. Are you sure?

Comment: I think so. I type searched for classes found in the axis jar and the only place they showed was the axis.jar. Normally when I type search the WAS Runtime shows up if its got it.